# How to create clusters in a one-dimensional space that would minimize the variance in the clusters?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

We have numeric data in one-dimensional arrays where adjacency matters, e.g. `[34,66,87,97,105,43,96]`

We want to cluster together those values, based on proximity, to minimize the variance in the sums. For any array, we know the number of clusters needed beforehand.

For our example array, we would want 3 clusters, so:

```
[{34,66,87},{97,105},{43,96}] produces [187,202,139], var: 722
[{34,66},{87,97},{105,43,96}] produces [100,184,244], var: 900
```

We're looking ideally for a solution in Python, but we're also looking for the right language for the kind of problem we're dealing with here.

Comment: It sounds like an assignment problem. Expect there is something handy in the combinatorial optimisation literature (which I'm not very familiar with). I know Google's ortools Python package deals with these sorts of problems.